# Class 'javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane' does not support property 'controller'

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml, borderpane

I am using `BorderPane` as a root pane of `FXML` file. However, the compiler complains that `BorderPane` has no `controller` property! How to bind a controller class to a `FXML` whose root is `BorderPane`?

```
<BorderPane id="rootPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.saei.explorer.FXMLDocumentController">
```

I am using `BorderPane` because of its capability of stretching the layout on re-sizing the window.

Comment: `AnchorPane` also stretches the layout on re-sizing the window.

Comment: What's the error and when are you seeing it? There is no "compiler" error - FXML files are not compiled.

Comment: OK, the parser complains.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oops, it turns out that I used `xmlns` property of JavaFX 8 within JavaFX 2.2 environment. I just replaced:

```
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
```

with:

```
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
```

and it works now!